# different between C struct bitfields on char and on int

Tags: c, struct, bit, sizeof, bit-fields

When using bitfields in C, I found out differences I did not expect related to the actual type that is used to declare the fields.

I didn't find any clear explanation. Now, the problem is identified, so if though there is no clear response, this post may be useful to anyone facing the same issue. 
Still if some can point to a formal explanation, this coudl be great.

The following structure, takes 2 bytes in memory.

```
struct {
  char field0 : 1; // 1 bit  - bit 0 
  char field1 : 2; // 2 bits - bits 2 down to 1
  char field2 ;    // 8 bits - bits 15 down to 8
} reg0;
```

This one takes 4 bytes in memory, the question is why ?

```
struct {
  int  field0 : 1; // 1 bit  - bit 0 
  int  field1 : 2; // 2 bits - bits 2 down to 1
  char field2 ;    // 8 bits - bits 15 down to 8
} reg1;
```

In both cases, the bits are organized in memory in the same way: field 2 is always taking bits 15 down to 8.

I tried to find some literarure on the subject, but still can't get a clear explanation.

The two most appropriate links I can found are:

- http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/
- http://www.msg.ucsf.edu/local/programs/IBM_Compilers/C:C++/html/language/ref/clrc03defbitf.htm

However, none really explains really why the second structure is taking 4 bytes. Actually reading carefully, I would even expect the structure to take 2 bytes.

In both cases,

- field0 takes 1 bit
- field1 takes 2 bits
- field2 takes 8 bits, and is aligned on the first available byte address

Hence, the useful data requires 2 bytes in both cases.

So what is behind the scene that makes reg1 to take 4 bytes ?

Full Code Example:

```
#include "stdio.h"
// Register Structure using char
typedef struct {
    // Reg0
    struct _reg0_bitfieldsA {
      char field0 : 1;
      char field1 : 2;
      char field2 ;
    } reg0;

    // Nextreg
    char NextReg;

} regfileA_t;

// Register Structure using int
typedef struct {
    // Reg1
    struct  _reg1_bitfieldsB {
      int field0 : 1;
      int field1 : 2;
      char field2 ;
    } reg1;

    // Reg
    char NextReg;
} regfileB_t;


regfileA_t regsA;
regfileB_t regsB;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int* ptrA, *ptrB;

    printf("sizeof(regsA) == %-0d\n",sizeof(regsA));   // prints 3 - as expected
    printf("sizeof(regsB) == %-0d\n",sizeof(regsB));   // prints 8 - why ?
    printf("\n");
    printf("sizeof(regsA.reg0) == %-0d\n",sizeof(regsA.reg0)); // prints 2 - as epxected
    printf("sizeof(regsB.reg0) == %-0d\n",sizeof(regsB.reg1)); // prints 4 - int bit fields tells the struct to use 4 bytes then.
    printf("\n");
    printf("addrof(regsA.reg0) == 0x%08x\n",(int)(&regsA.reg0));     // 0x0804A028
    printf("addrof(regsA.reg1) == 0x%08x\n",(int)(&regsA.NextReg));  // 0x0804A02A = prev + 2
    printf("addrof(regsB.reg0) == 0x%08x\n",(int)(&regsB.reg1));     // 0x0804A020
    printf("addrof(regsB.reg1) == 0x%08x\n",(int)(&regsB.NextReg));  // 0x0804A024 = prev + 4 - my register is not at the righ place then.
    printf("\n");

    regsA.reg0.field0 = 1;
    regsA.reg0.field1 = 3;
    regsA.reg0.field2 = 0xAB;

    regsB.reg1.field0 = 1;
    regsB.reg1.field1 = 3;
    regsB.reg1.field2 = 0xAB;

    ptrA = (int*)&regsA;
    ptrB = (int*)&regsB;
    printf("regsA.reg0.value == 0x%08x\n",(int)(*ptrA)); // 0x0000AB07 (expected)
    printf("regsB.reg0.value == 0x%08x\n",(int)(*ptrB)); // 0x0000AB07 (expected)

    return 0;
}
```

When I first write the struct I expected to get reg1 to take only 2 bytes, hence the next register was at the offset = 2.

Comment: Your first bit-field (using `char` as the type) is actually not standard, it's an implementation-specific extension. See e.g. [this bitfield reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field) for the possible types, as well as more information.

Comment: The bitfield stuff as a whole is pretty much implementation-specified, and it doesn't make sense to discuss the sizes except when discussing a specific implementation. You don't name your implementation!

Comment: Thanks for the links.
I'm fine with the implementation specific point.
Note that I have exactly the same behavior on different compilers and cross compilers. Gcc on Linux, and ARM Gcc from Mentor Code Sourcery for instancE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relevant part of the standard is [C11/C17 6.7.2.1p11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p11):

> 11. An implementation may allocate **any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field**. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

that, in connection with [C11/C17 6.7.2.1p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p5)

> 5. A. bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some **other *implementation-defined type***. It is implementation-defined whether atomic types are permitted.

and that you're using `char` means that there is nothing to discuss in general - for a specific implementation check the compiler manuals. [Here's the one for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html).

From the 2 excerpts it follows that an implementation is free to use *absolutely whatever types it wants to* to implement the bitfields - it could even use `int64_t` for both of these cases having the structure of size 16 bytes. The only thing a conforming implementation *must do* is to pack the bits within the chosen addressable storage unit if enough space remains.

---

For GCC on [System-V ABI on 386-compatible (32-bit processors)](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf), the following stands:

> *Plain* bit-fields (that is, those neither `signed` nor `unsigned`) always have non- negative values. Although they may have type `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, (which can have negative values),
>   these bit-fields have the same range as a bit-field of the same size
>   with the corresponding `unsigned` type. Bit-fields obey the same
>   size and alignment rules as other structure and union members, with
>   the following additions:
>
> - Bit-fields are allocated from right to left (least to most significant).
> - A bit-field must entirely reside in a storage unit appropriate for its declared type. Thus a bit-field never crosses its unit boundary.
> - Bit-fields may share a storage unit with other `struct`/`union` members, including members that are not bit-fields. Of course,
>     `struct` members occupy different parts of the storage unit.
> - Unnamed bit-fields' types do not affect the alignment of a structure or union, although individual bit-fields' member offsets obey the
>     alignment constraints.

i.e. in System-V ABI, 386, `int f: 1` says that the bit-field `f` must be *within an `int`*. If entire bytes of space remains, a following `char` within the same struct will be *packed inside this `int`*, even if it is not a bit-field.

Using this knowledge, the layout for

```
struct {
  int  a : 1; // 1 bit  - bit 0 
  int  b : 2; // 2 bits - bits 2 down to 1
  char c ;    // 8 bits - bits 15 down to 8
} reg1;
```

will be

```
                     1                     2                 3  
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 
|a b b x x x x x|c c c c c c c c|x x x x x x x x|x x x x x x x x|               

<------------------------------ int ---------------------------->
```

and the layout for

```
struct {
  char  a : 1; // 1 bit  - bit 0 
  char b : 2; // 2 bits - bits 2 down to 1
  char c ;    // 8 bits - bits 15 down to 8
} reg1;
```

will be

```
                    1
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 
|a b b x x x x x|c c c c c c c c|

<---- char ----><---- char ---->
```

So there are tricky edge cases. Compare the 2 definitions here:

```
struct x {
    short a : 2;  
    short b : 15;
    char  c ; 
};

struct y {
    int a : 2;  
    int b : 15;
    char  c ; 
};
```

Because the bit-field must not cross the unit boundary, the `struct x` members `a` and `b` need to go to different shorts. Then there is not enough space to accommodate the `char c`, so it must come after that. And the entire struct must be suitably aligned for `short` so it will be 6 bytes on i386. The latter however, will pack `a` and `b` in the 17 lowest bits of the `int`, and since there is still one entire addressable byte left within the `int`, the `c` will be packed here too, and hence `sizeof (struct y)` will be *4*.

---

Finally, you must really specify whether the `int` or `char` is signed or not - the default might be not what you expect! Standard leaves it up to the implementation, and GCC has a compile-time switch to change them.

Comment: This is **all** that the standard explains. Then the GCC documents, then you need to find out the ABI that they're targetting! My expectation would be that if not 2, the `int` case should take 8 bytes... and if not that...

Comment: So, the conclusion is that the size of the container struct is **at least** the number of bits required to hold the bit fields.
The actual size cannot be determined by the standard and is implementation specific.We do see structure of registers defined one after the other in such a way. Commonly they are 32 bits registers and it just happens to work. 
If one wants smaller registers, there is no guarantee we'll get it right.

Comment: No, they're always in that order, and you need to properly lay out the bits in the fields to find out what the size needs to be.

Comment: @Francois the `int` takes 4 bytes. but you need to lay out the bitfield using the algorithm to find out how much space it takes, a superficial glimpse does not tell. I'll give you an example:

Comment: That is what I was looking for: 
__A bit-field must entirely reside in a storage unit appropriate for its declared type. Thus a bit-field never crosses its unit boundary.__
Thanks a lot.